# Can I power my MacBook Pro through my LG external monitor?

Tags: usb, macbook, external-display

My 13-inch MacBook Pro was shipped brand-new from Apple in March 2020. As explained in [a recent SuperUser Q and A](https://superuser.com/questions/1571649/how-can-one-connect-more-high-speed-external-devices-to-a-13-inch-year-2020-mac), I am trying to operate several high-throughput peripherals with this computer:

1. SuperDrive for watching DVD movies
2. LG external display
3. mechanical spinning external hard drive for Time Machine
4. mechanical spinning external hard drive for for large data transfers
5. flash drives for occasional smaller data transfers

An answer by @spiff to [the above-cited SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/1571649/how-can-one-connect-more-high-speed-external-devices-to-a-13-inch-year-2020-mac)
states that if I had the 27MD5KL 5K display, I would be able to power the MacBook Pro through that display. Thus, of the two USB receptacles on the left of the MacBook Pro, only one would be occupied and I could plug another high-throughput device into the 2nd.

As things stand, my current display, purchased from Amazon.com on 10 June 2019, is: 2019 LG 27MD5KA-B 27" 5K Resolution Monitor, 5120 x 2880 WFHD IPS Ultrafine Display, 1200:1 Contrast Ratio, Thunderbolt 3, P3 99% Color Spectrum, Built-in Camera & Speaker (Renewed). In the back, it has 1 "Host (Mac) connection port" and 3 "USB expansion port"s. To my inexperienced eye, its back looks just like the back of the 27MD5KL 5K display that one can see at
[lg.com 27MD5KL 5K](https://www.lg.com/us/displays/lg-27md5kl-b-5k-uhd-led-display#).

Currently, both receptacles on the left of my MacBook Pro are occupied:

1. One goes to the Apple charger (i.e., the power adapter which plugs into USA 120V wall power).
2. The other is plugged, via an Apple adapter, into the "Host (Mac) connection port" in the back of the LG display.

I have tried unplugging number 1, in hopes that the wire running from the "Host (Mac) connection port" would provide power for the MacBook Pro. But when I do this, the computer switches to battery power.

Is there any way to have just one wire running between this display and this computer? Or is the feature described by @spiff only available if I purchase the apparently newer LG display?

Answer (score 0):

LG's website for your model says that it can provide 85W of charging power and specifically mentions MacBook Pros.

Try disconnecting and reconnecting the Thunderbolt cable after disconnecting the Apple charger. Your MBP likely can only accept power from one device at a time, and it probably prefers Apple chargers. So it probably told the LG monitor not to send power. Maybe the MBP or the LG monitor was not smart enough to handle renegotiating power delivery after the Apple charger was disconnected.

Also, make sure you're using the Thunderbolt 3 cable that came with the display. Other Thunderbolt 3 cables might not have thick enough power wires for 85W of power delivery.